# Binary Search Tree in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I just implemented binary search tree as described in Cormen's algorithm book. I'm not interested in correctness or performance of the implementation. I'm looking for reviews, comments on code style and suggestions on what can be done to improve readability of the code and make it more concise, or any general issues you noticed.

To make things easy, I assume that duplicate values won't be inserted.

The code is a bit long but most methods are symmetric and some lines are just comments. Feel free to review as much as you want. Partial reviews are welcome.

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    """
    BinarySearchTree implementation from Cormen's Introduction to
    Algorithm book

    The implementation assumes that there is no duplicates in the tree.
    """

    class Node:

        def __init__(self, value, parent=None):
            self.value = value
            self.parent = parent
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        self._root = None
        if iterable is not None:
            for element in iterable:
                self.insert(element)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self._search(self._root, item) is not None

    def __len__(self):
        return self._count(self._root)

    def _count(self, node):
        """
        Returns the size of subtree rooted on given node
        Returns 0 if root is None
        """
        if node is None:
            return 0

        return 1 + self._count(node.left) + self._count(node.right)

    def search(self, value):
        """
        Finds and returns the given value.
        Returns None if not found in BST.
        """
        node = self._search(self._root, value)
        if node is None:
            return None
        return node.value

    def _search(self, node, value):
        """
        Searches node with specified value under subtree
        rooted on given node, Returns None if value is not found
        """

        if node is None:
            return None

        if node.value == value:
            return node

        if value < node.value:
            return self._search(node.left, value)

        else:
            return self._search(node.right, value)

    def insert(self, element):
        """Inserts given element to BST."""
        if self._root is None:
            self._root = self.Node(element)
            return

        self._insert(self._root, element)

    def _insert(self, node, element):
        """
        Insert given value to subtree rooted on given node.
        It is assumed that root is not None
        """
        if element <= node.value:

            if node.left is None:
                node.left = self.Node(element, node)

            else:
                self._insert(node.left, element)

        else:

            if node.right is None:
                node.right = self.Node(element, node)

            else:
                self._insert(node.right, element)

    def remove(self, element):
        """
        Removes the given element from BST.
        Throws ValueError if element is not in the BST
        """
        node = self._search(self._root, element)
        if node is None:
            raise ValueError("Given element is not found in BST")

        parent = node.parent
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:  # leaf node
            if parent is not None:
                if parent.left is node:
                    parent.left = None
                else:
                    parent.right = None
            else:
                self._root = None

        elif node.left is None:
            if parent is None:
                self._root = node.right
            elif parent.left is node:
                parent.left = node.right
            else:
                parent.right = node.right
            node.right.parent = parent

        elif node.right is None:
            if parent is None:
                self._root = node.left
            elif parent.left is node:
                parent.left = node.left
            else:
                parent.right = node.left
            node.left.parent = parent

        else:
            if parent is None:
                successor_node = self._maximum(node)
                successor_node.parent.right = None
                successor_node.parent = None
                successor_node.left = node.left
                successor_node.right = node.right
                self._root = successor_node

            elif parent.left is node:
                successor_node = self._maximum(node)
                successor_node.parent.right = None
                successor_node.parent = parent
                successor_node.left = node.left
                successor_node.right = node.right

            else:
                predecessor_node = self._minimum(node)
                predecessor_node.parent.left = None
                predecessor_node.parent = parent
                predecessor_node.left = node.left
                predecessor_node.right = node.right

    def maximum(self):
        """
        Returns the maximum element in BST
        Throws ValueError if BST is empty
        """
        if self._root is None:
            raise ValueError("BST is empty")

        return self._maximum(self._root).value

    def _maximum(self, node):
        """Returns the maximum node of subtree rooted on given node."""
        while node.right is not None:
            node = node.right
        return node

    def minimum(self):
        """
        Returns the minimum element in BST
        Throws ValueError if BST is empty
        """
        if self._root is None:
            raise ValueError("BST is empty")

        return self._minimum(self._root).value

    def _minimum(self, node):
        """Returns the minimum node of subtree rooted on given node."""
        while node.left is not None:
            node = node.left
        return node

    def successor(self, element):
        """
        Returns successor of given element in BST.
        If given element is not in the BST, throws ValueError
        """
        node = self._search(self._root, element)
        if node is None:
            raise ValueError("Given element is not found in BST")

        successor_node = self._successor(node)
        if successor_node is None:
            return None
        return successor_node.value

    def _successor(self, node):
        """Returns successor node of given node."""
        if node.right is None:
            if node.parent is None:
                return None
            else:
                parent = node.parent
                while parent is not None and parent.right is node:
                    node = parent
                    parent = parent.parent
                if parent is None:
                    return None
                else:
                    return parent
        else:
            node = node.right
            return self._minimum(node)

    def predecessor(self, element):
        """
        Returns precedessor of given element in BST.
        If given element is not in the BST, throws ValueError
        """
        node = self._search(self._root, element)
        if node is None:
            raise ValueError("Given element is not found in BST")

        predecessor_node = self._predecessor(node)
        if predecessor_node is None:
            return None
        return predecessor_node.value

    def _predecessor(self, node):
        """Returns predecessor node of given node."""
        if node.left is None:
            if node.parent is None:
                return None
            else:
                parent = node.parent
                while parent is not None and parent.left is node:
                    node = parent
                    parent = parent.parent
                if parent is None:
                    return None
                else:
                    return parent
        else:
            node = node.left
            return self._maximum(node)
```

I also uploaded it on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Shathra/dd34223e5a4d9cfa085ce147d23bada4) with a test file.